# Python windows service error(import win32serviceutil ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32serviceutil')

Tags: python, pywin32, python-venv

I have developed a windows service in python that installs fine but gives that error when I start it.
It seems that the windows is unable to access the venv folder,How do I rectify this?

I have deleted the Venv and reinstalled the dependacies pywin32 included but nothing has changed.

here is the code example

```py
import os
import sys
import win32serviceutil
import win32service
import win32event
import servicemanager
import requests
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error

class AmanoReportingService(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "AmanoReportingService"
    _svc_display_name_ = "Amano Reporting Service"
    _svc_description_ = "Windows service that retrieves data from Amano SOAP API and inserts it into a MySQL database"
    
    def __init__(self, args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
        self.stop_event = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)
        self.session = requests.Session()
        
        self.auth_params = {
            "getPrepaid": {
                "username": "EASTRA",
                "password": "E8MVDAMjLkytjD2x"
            },
            "getPayments": {
                "username": "EASTRA",
                "password": "E8MVDAMjLkytjD2x"
            }
        }
        
        self.prepaid_fields = [
            "transid",
            "card_no",
            "prepaidType",
            "entry_timestamp",
            "entry_gate",
            "paid_on",
            "pay_station",
            "exit_timestamp",
            "exit_gate",
            "amount_payable",
            "amount_paid",
            "payment_method",
            "park_status",
            "trans_description",
            "tag",
            "car_reg"
        ]
        
        self.payments_fields = [
            "id",
            "dateTimePayment",
            "dateTimeIn",
            "entry_device",
            "entry_lpn",
            "dateTimeOut",
            "exit_device",
            "exit_lpn",
            "paymentType",
            "ticketType",
            "referenceNumber",
            "originalTransactionAmount",
            "discountAmount",
            "transactionAmount",
            "surchargeAmount",
            "finalAmount",
            "deviceId",
            "ticketNumber",
            "validationCode"
        ]
        
    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.stop_event)
        
    def main(self):
        try:
            cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='Pa$$w0rd', host='localhost', database='kaps')
            
            while True:
                # Get prepaid transactions
                for from_time, to_time in self.get_time_intervals():
                    for trans in self.get_prepaids(from_time, to_time):
                        self.insert_prepaids(cnx, trans)
                
                # Get parking payments
                for from_time, to_time in self.get_time_intervals():
                    for payment in self.get_payments(from_time, to_time):
                        self.insert_payments(cnx, payment)
                        
                # Sleep for 10 minutes
                if win32event.WaitForSingleObject(self.stop_event, 600000) == win32event.WAIT_OBJECT_0:
                    # Stop signal received
                    break
                    
        except Error as e:
            # Handle database errors
            servicemanager.LogErrorMsg(f"AmanoReportingService: Error connecting to MySQL database - {e}")
        finally:
            # Close database connection
            if cnx.is_connected():
                cnx.close()
                
    def get_time_intervals(self):
        # Define time intervals
        # Change these values as needed
        from_times = [
            "2023-02-09 11:00:00",
            "2023-02-09 11:10:00",
            "2023-02-09 11:20:00"
        ]
        to_times = [
        "2023-02-09 11:09:59",
        "2023-02-09 11:19:59",
        "2023-02-09 11:29:59"
        ]
        return zip(from_times, to_times)

    def get_prepaids(self, from_time, to_time): 
        # Get prepaid transactions from Amano SOAP API
        params = {
            "username": self.auth_params["getPrepaid"]["username"],
            "password": self.auth_params["getPrepaid"]["password"],
            "dateFrom": from_time,
            "dateTo": to_time
        }
        response = self.session.get("http://alex.kaps.co.ke/amanoreporting/API.php?wsdl", params=params)
        data = response.json()
        return data

    def get_payments(self, from_time, to_time):
        # Get parking payments from Amano SOAP API
        params = {
         "username": self.auth_params["getPayments"]["username"],
         "password": self.auth_params["getPayments"]["password"],
         "dateFrom": from_time,
            "dateTo": to_time
        }
        response = self.session.get("http://alex.kaps.co.ke/amanoreporting/API.php?wsdl", params=params)
        data = response.json()
        return data

    def insert_prepaids(self, cnx, prepaid):
        # Insert prepaid transaction into database
        values = []
        for field in self.prepaid_fields:
            value = prepaid.get(field)
            if value is None:
                value = ""
            values.append(value)
        query = f"INSERT INTO prepaid_transactions ({', '.join(self.prepaid_fields)}) VALUES ({', '.join(['%s'] * len(self.prepaid_fields))})"
        cursor = cnx.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query, tuple(values))
        cnx.commit()
    
    def insert_payments(self, cnx, payment):
        # Insert parking payment into database
        values = []
        for field in self.payments_fields:
            value = payment.get(field)
            if value is None:
                value = ""
            values.append(value)
        query = f"INSERT INTO parking_payments ({', '.join(self.payments_fields)}) VALUES ({', '.join(['%s'] * len(self.payments_fields))})"
        cursor = cnx.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query, tuple(values))
        cnx.commit()

if __name__ == '__main__':`enter code here`
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(AmanoReportingService)
```

Comment: What is the error exactly?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The problem is that windows is not able to access the virtual environment that houses the site package necessary to run the app